# usage of Aggregate function inR

Tags: r

My question is how to find aggregate of values in a variable in an excel file using R, I have read the file into R, but tried to use the aggregate function but it is not working. I installed the plyr function also. do we ahve to convert the read file to dataframe to use this function?

Comment: "tried to use the aggregate function but it is not working" - that is not very informative. Last time I used it, it did work. Can you add some details?

Comment: You need to provide details about its current structure. The most common procedure is to use read.table or read.csv which results in a dataframe object. If you didn't do that, then we do not have enough information to help.

Comment: the file is in excel, so I read into R using read.xlsx and the file has 10 var and 180 ob all the values are numeric. then straight away used aggregate function. y<-aggregate(btw~race, data =x, mean). btw is birth weight and race is num , 1,2,3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For example:

```
aggregate(df["x"],df["group"],function(x) mean(x,na.rm=T))
```

Or just

```
aggregate(df["x"],df["group"], FUN=mean)
```

You can use `plyr` too

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .group, summarise, m = mean(yourVar, na.rm=T))
```

You may have NAs in your data? Which might mean you need `na.rm=T`.  Look at http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Summarizing_data/ for guidance.

Comment: Data is 5 col with headers and num values! read into r using read.xlsx!

Comment: It seems you've reached 50 reputation -- now you can comment/flag instead of answering when you see duplicate questions!

Comment: @MerryKumar if this answers the question can you accept it please. Next time read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask be clear on what you've tried (give code examples) and what your data looks like, it's impossible to answer properly otherwise.

Comment: avg<- aggregate(bwt~lwt+race, data=y, sum) , I have done it. Thank you. Was able to successfully execute it!